# highlight.js for Markdown uses one colour everywhere

Tags: markdown, highlight.js

The [official demo of markdown](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) is awesome. I tried to follow the guide, but the result does not match my expectation, the colour of words is just green.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>highlight.js example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/styles/darkula.min.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre><code class="markdown">
    # hello world

    you can write text [with links](http://example.com) inline or [link references][1].

    * one _thing_ has *em*phasis
    * two __things__ are **bold**

    [1]: http://example.com

    ---

    hello world
    ===========

    > markdown is so cool

    so are code segments

    1. one thing (yeah!)
    2. two thing `i can write code`, and `more` wipee!
</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your entire code example is indented with 4 spaces. In Markdown syntax that means pre-formatted code, and highlight.js, with the theme you chose, colors code blocks in green.

Remove 4 spaces from the start of each line and everything works as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>highlight.js example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/styles/darkula.min.css">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <pre><code class="markdown">
# hello world

you can write text [with links](http://example.com) inline or [link references][1].

* one _thing_ has *em*phasis
* two __things__ are **bold**

[1]: http://example.com

---

hello world
===========

> markdown is so cool

so are code segments

1. one thing (yeah!)
2. two thing `i can write code`, and `more` wipee!
</code></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also realized that mistakeT_T

Comment: if you are dynamically adding content, call `hljs.highlightBlock(element);` again